# Unable to login to https://api.cloudfoundry.com

Tags: cloud-foundry

despite the fact that i have setup everything i am still unable to login:

C:>vmc target

[https://api.cloudfoundry.com]

C:> vmc info

VMware's Cloud Application Platform
For support visit http://support.cloudfoundry.com

Target:   https://api.cloudfoundry.com (v0.999)
Client:   v0.3.23

C:>vmc login xxxxxxxxxxx -t

Attempting login to [https://api.cloudfoundry.com]
Password: ********
Problem with login to 'https://api.cloudfoundry.com', A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not pr
operly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. -
connect(2), try again or register for an account.

Has anyone an idea what I am possibly missing here?

Comment: After "gem update vmc" I'm running vmc 0.4.7, and have you tried just "vmc login"? Let it prompt you for the answers. Let's go from there.

Answer (score 1):

Please update your vmc client

```
gem update vmc
```